# Angularjs: How to add values in UI-grid for column which is a percentage value

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

Angularjs:

I have ui-grid in angularjs which one field as Percentage? 
This grid initially has ne row and new rows can be added, but once the percentage column reaches 100%, new rows can not be added.

How to add values in UI-grid for column and then disable adding new rows.

Answer (score 0):

Used ng-change method. "grid.appScope" was missing and thay why it was not calling the method when I initially wrote it.

ng-change=\"**grid.appScope.**$ctrl.addAllocation()\"